# Is there a way to recalculate existing values in df based on conditions? - Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with Employees and their hours for different categories.

I need to recalculate only specific categories (**OT, MILE and REST Categories SHOULD NOT Be Updated, ALL Other Should be updated**) ONLY if OT category is present under Empl_Id.

```
data = {'Empl_Id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
     'Category': ["MILE", "REST", "OT", "TRVL", "REG", "ADMIN", "REST", "REG", "MILE", "OT", "TRVL", "REST", "MAT", "REG"], 
     'Value': [43, 0.7, 6.33, 2.67, 52, 22, 1.17, 16.5, 73.6, 4.75, 1.33, 2.5, 5.5, 52.25]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df
```

| Empl_Id | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MILE | 43 |
| 1 | REST | 0.7 |
| 1 | OT | 6.33 |
| 1 | TRVL | 2.67 |
| 1 | REG | 52 |
| 2 | ADMIN | 22 |
| 2 | REST | 1.17 |
| 2 | REG | 16.5 |
| 3 | MILE | 73.6 |
| 3 | OT | 4.75 |
| 3 | TRVL | 1.33 |
| 3 | REST | 2.5 |
| 3 | MAT | 5.5 |
| 3 | REG | 52.25 |

The Logic is to:

**1) Find % of OT Hours from Total Hours (OT, REST and MILE don't count):**

- 1st Empl_Id: 6.33 (OT) / 2.67 (TRVL) + 52 (REG) = 6.33 / 54.67 = 11.58 %
- 2nd Empl_Id: OT Hours Not present, nothing should be updated
- 3rd Empl_Id: 4.75 (OT) / 1.33 (TRVL) + 5.5 (MAT) + 52.25 (REG) = 4.75 / 59.08 = 8.04 %

**2) Substract % of OT from each category (OT, REST and MILE don't count):**

| Empl_Id | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MILE | 43 |
| 1 | REST | 0.7 |
| 1 | OT | 6.33 |
| 1 | TRVL | **2.67 - 11.58 % (0.31) = 2.36** |
| 1 | REG | **52 - 11.58 % (6.02) = 45.98** |
| 2 | ADMIN | 22 |
| 2 | REST | 1.17 |
| 2 | REG | 16.5 |
| 3 | MILE | 73.6 |
| 3 | OT | 4.75 |
| 3 | TRVL | **1.33 - 8.04 % (0.11) = 1.22** |
| 3 | REST | 2.5 |
| 3 | MAT | **5.5 - 8.04 % (0.44) = 5.06** |
| 3 | REG | **52.25 - 8.04 % (4.2) = 48.05** |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
keep = ['OT', 'MILE', 'REST']

# get factor
factor = (df.groupby(df['Empl_Id'])
            .apply(lambda g: g.loc[g['Category'].eq('OT'),'Value'].sum()
                            /g.loc[~g['Category'].isin(keep),'Value'].sum()
                  )
            .rsub(1)
         )

# update
df.loc[~df['Category'].isin(keep), 'Value'] *= df['Empl_Id'].map(factor)
```

output:

```
    Empl_Id Category      Value
0         1     MILE  43.000000
1         1     REST   0.700000
2         1       OT   6.330000
3         1     TRVL   2.360852
4         1      REG  45.979148
5         2    ADMIN  22.000000
6         2     REST   1.170000
7         2      REG  16.500000
8         3     MILE  73.600000
9         3       OT   1.750000
10        3     TRVL   1.290604
11        3     REST   2.500000
12        3      MAT   5.337085
13        3      REG  50.702310
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank You very much. Could You please explain what *= does in the last line?

Comment: This is in place multiplication